# Notify users when their first few flags have been handled

Tags: feature-request, flags, notifications

I feel many new users don't notice when the moderators respond to their flags, or don't know where to look for that feedback – i.e., they are unaware of the flag history links on their profile page.

That's not good; the users may think nobody cared for their flags, and then leave the site, stop flagging, or keep making the same mistakes over and over when flagging.

Could they be notified when their first few flags are resolved? The notification could either link to the flag history directly, or to a help page that clearly indicates where the flag history links are.

Comment: Good idea. I happened to be ignorant about the reactions on my flags until I hit more or less by accident the right link to see my flagging history.