# Notification for resolved flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, notifications, flag-history

Is it possible to get a notification when one of our flags has been resolved? This request is similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269271/notify-users-when-their-first-few-flags-have-been-handled), but I think it would be good for all users, not just the first few flags. Aside from many new users not knowing where they can see all of their flags, it gets annoying to go back and check on the status every so often.

I figure one option is just to have a simple notification that says "Your flag has been resolved." Another option is to specify the outcome - "Your recent flag was marked helpful/disputed/declined." and maybe include any moderator messages in the notification. Any of these would be fine, but it would just be nice to be told when a flag rather than having to actively check on the status. This seems like a pretty simple functionality that should be possible.

Comment: The problem is this will get incredibly noisy for users who flag a lot of items. There are a lot of users who flag a lot of content, their inbox will be full of noise. If someone uses all their 100 flags for a day, that's a bunch of junk to wade through in the inbox.

Comment: @bluefeet Or maybe even a summary notification? Every hour/day/something get a notification of "You have X resolved flags"? Or maybe have the option to turn on/off notifications for flags, though that would be a completely new functionality.

Comment: @DavidK Then you haven't solved your problem.  If you simply want to see once a day if you have resolved flags, then that means you're only checking your flag history once a day.  If you've flagged stuff in the last day you probably do have some resolved flags to see, and if you're the type of person that wants to see the resolved flag immediately, rather than seeing it the next day when you check on it, then this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @Servy That is a good point, though it does solve the problem for new users who are unaware of the feature, or for flags you've forgotten about.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228267/show-declined-flags-in-inbox (which is probably a better idea, IMO)

Comment: Or, actually, this is the one I was looking for: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239738/send-custom-flag-responses-to-messages-inbox

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes, agree with you on Shokhet's proposal. That problem would be solved with notifications for all flags, but I think if my proposal is declined, that one should at least be implemented. It certainly has a lot of support but seems to have been forgotten.

Answer (score -2):

Meh.

What are you going to *do* with that information? If a flag was acted on, there's nothing else for you to do. If a flag is still pending, there's nothing for you to do, unless you're thinking about pestering the moderators or something, but a lot of flags are handled by community action and not the moderators anyway.

It *might* be useful to know when you've gotten a flag wrong, but if you get too many wrong the system will let you know about it. The occasional incorrect flag is no big deal. Mistakes happen.

I don't see a need for this feature.

Comment: What are you going to do with upvote notifications? Or reading usernames of posts (for example seeing "ale" as the author here)? There is a lot to SE that has no actionable element to it.